# In SQL, how can I insert a static column value while doing a INSERT INTO SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write an SQL statement that will copy rows and insert them into the same table; however, on one of the fields, I want to write a static value for each row copied.  I'm not sure how to do this, but here's what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
SELECT  [NAME]
  ,[DESC]
  ,[MODULE]
  ,[OWNER]  <=== I want all newly inserted rows to have "TERRY" as the owner
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
WHERE OWNER = 'SAM' AND MODULE = 'ACC'
```

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Just Replace `[OWNER]` with `'TERRY'`

Comment: OT: Always supply column names in the INSERT statement (ie, `INSERT INTO TABLEX(col1, ..., colN) SELECT ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
SELECT  [NAME]
  ,[DESC]
  ,[MODULE]
  ,'Terry'  <=== I want all newly inserted rows to have "TERRY" as the owner
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
WHERE OWNER = 'SAM' AND MODULE = 'ACC'
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do the work -

```
INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
SELECT  [NAME]
  ,[DESC]
  ,[MODULE]
  ,'Terry' AS [OWNER]  
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
WHERE OWNER = 'SAM' AND MODULE = 'ACC'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
SELECT  [NAME]
,[DESC]
,[MODULE]
,'TERRY'  
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
WHERE OWNER = 'SAM' AND MODULE = 'ACC'
```

Comment: Interesting, what does adding [OWNER} after do? ETA. I see, works same as 'AS'. Still redundant in this context, but I do see it works.

Comment: TABLEX  have a column [OWNER] and static value 'TERRY' will get inserted into column [OWNER] of TABLEX, even if I remove [OWNER] from 'TERRY'[OWNER]  then also it will work and the answer which i have posted will also work

Comment: Still redundant. You are defining the 'source' column, not the destination. The field order is based on the INSERT INTO and the fact that it does not specify the column names there means it will go in field order. Adding the [OWNER] has no impact on where the value will end up, so therefore redundant.

Comment: yah i just checked , even though this soln works but [OWNER] is redundant  , thanks for clarifying that "The field order is based on the INSERT INTO " and thanks for giving your time

Answer (score 1):

Is `[Owner]` a *string-type* column and you want to fill in 'TERRY' literally, try this:

```
INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
SELECT  [NAME]
  ,[DESC]
  ,[MODULE]
  ,'TERRY'
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
WHERE OWNER = 'SAM' AND MODULE = 'ACC'
```

If - what I'd suggest! - the owner is a foreign key to another table, and you are sure, that this `Terry` exists, you'd use a sub-select:

```
INSERT INTO [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
SELECT  [NAME]
  ,[DESC]
  ,[MODULE]
  ,(SELECT SomeID FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn='TERRY')
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[TABLEX]
WHERE OWNER = 'SAM' AND MODULE = 'ACC'
```

But your `WHERE`-clause lets me think, that the owner is a string column...

- You should really **re-think this design**!